# Apache Derby - java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, derby

First, this is my first time with Apache Derby. I am using netbeans, willing to use embedded apache derby, and I followed the following tutorial for configuring and installing the database. Then, I attached the derby.jar file to my project, using project properties.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html#starting

The attached image will show my database status in netbeans
[image]

My database name is "contact". Table name is "FRIENDS".

Following is my test code

```
**DatabaseConnector.java**

import java.sql.*;

public class DataBaseConnector
{
    private Connection con;

    public DataBaseConnector()
    {

    }

    private void createConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:/Users/yohan/.netbeans-derby/contact","yohan","xyz");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void insertData(int id, String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        createConnection();
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into FRIENDS values(?,?,?)");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.setString(1, firstName);
            ps.setString(2, lastName);

            int result = ps.executeUpdate();

            if(result>0)
            {
                System.out.println("Data Inserted");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Something happened");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }


}
```

**DatabaseUI.java**

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DatabaseUI extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel firstName, id, lastName;
    private JTextField idTxt, firstNameTxt, lastNameTxt;
    private JButton ok;

    public DatabaseUI()
    {
     firstName = new JLabel("First Name: ");
     lastName = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
     id = new JLabel("ID: ");

     firstNameTxt = new JTextField(10);
     lastNameTxt = new JTextField(10);
     idTxt = new JTextField(10);

     ok = new JButton("OK");
     ok.addActionListener(new OKAction());

     JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
     centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
     centerPanel.add(id);
     centerPanel.add(idTxt);
     centerPanel.add(firstName);
     centerPanel.add(firstNameTxt);
     centerPanel.add(lastName);
     centerPanel.add(lastNameTxt);
     centerPanel.add(new JPanel());
     centerPanel.add(ok);

     getContentPane().add(centerPanel,"Center");


     this.pack();
     this.setVisible(true);


    }

    private class OKAction implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            DataBaseConnector db = new DataBaseConnector();

            int id = Integer.parseInt(idTxt.getText());

            db.insertData(id, firstNameTxt.getText().trim(), lastNameTxt.getText().trim());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new DatabaseUI();
    }
}
```

But, when I am trying to insert data into the database, it is giving me the following error

```
run:
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:/Users/yohan/.netbeans-derby/contact' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1050169, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at DataBaseConnector.createConnection(DataBaseConnector.java:17)
    at DataBaseConnector.insertData(DataBaseConnector.java:40)
    at DatabaseUI$OKAction.actionPerformed(DatabaseUI.java:53)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:/Users/yohan/.netbeans-derby/contact' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1050169, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\Users\yohan\.netbeans-derby\contact.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\Users\yohan\.netbeans-derby\contact.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DataBaseConnector.insertData(DataBaseConnector.java:43)
    at DatabaseUI$OKAction.actionPerformed(DatabaseUI.java:53)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DataBaseConnector.closeConnection(DataBaseConnector.java:29)
    at DataBaseConnector.insertData(DataBaseConnector.java:65)
    at DatabaseUI$OKAction.actionPerformed(DatabaseUI.java:53)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

Why is this? Please help!

Apart from that first main question, I would like to ask another 2 questions.

2. I have to give the explicit location of the database as the connection here. But, when I give this to a client, how can I do that?
3. I have to start the database connection manually using netbeans. Is there anyway to start the database connection automatically? Using code?

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: This seems relevant: *"Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\Users\yohan\.netbeans-derby\contact."*

Comment: yes..But there is not! Or, at least, I didn't do it by my own! Is there any error in the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your program contains some misunderstandings and wrong assignments !**

- From your image you can see your DATABASE = contactDB not contact.
  "jdbc:derby:C:/Users/yohan/.netbeans-derby/contact" is **wrong**
  "jdbc:derby:C:/Users/yohan/.netbeans-derby/contactDB" now only the DB is correct.
  **Error:** Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\Users\yohan.netbeans-derby\contact.
- For the Con.String it's better not to use the PATH
  **will work** "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/Users/yohan/.netbeans-derby/contactDB","yohan","xyz"
  **better is** "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/contactDB","yohan","xyz"

It is better to specify the full Path to the table. Otherwise it is working only in Netbeans, with an already open table and a default schema.

- prepareStatement
  only **inside Netbeans** con.prepareStatement("insert **into FRIENDS** values(?,?,?)");
  **better** is con.prepareStatement("insert **into APP.FRIENDS** values(?,?,?)");

Now look at this !

```
    ps.setInt(1, id);
    ps.setString(1, firstName);
    ps.setString(2, lastName);
```

- First you set the **id** with setInt().
- Second Now you set the **id** with a **string** setString()  ( firstName !!!!!)
- Third at the end you override firstName with lastName and the lastName in the ps. is empty.

This will give you the next Error

It is better , when an **error occurs**, not to run the program further. The error list will grow up. It's hard to read. in your case the first Error is in **createConnection** and runs on !!

- Error createConnection
- Error con.prepareStatement("...
- Error ps.executeUpdate()
- Error closeConnection()

Test it with **boolean** and **if** !

```
private boolean createConnection()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/contactDB","yohan","xyz");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   
        System.out.println("Error getConnection");
        return false;
    }
 return true;   
}
```

**No need to run further if the connection fails.**

```
public void insertData(int id, String firstName, String lastName)
    {
       if (createConnection()) {
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO APP.FRIENDS values(?,?,?)");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.setString(2, firstName);
            ps.setString(3, lastName);
[...]
```

I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I really appreciate it. I edited it, and the connection fails! However, contactDB is the name of the URL, not the database. Database name is "contact". I did it by following the tutorial

Comment: Look at your Image `--contactDB--APP--FRIENDS`

Comment: Connection fails with " java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/Users/yohan/.netbeans-derby/contactDB"

Comment: add to your project the library `java DB Driver` (Properties -- Libraries -- Add Library...)

Comment: If in your Netbeans is no library `Java DB Driver` then manually add derbyclient.jar and derbynet.jar to your project

Comment: Thanks you! It worked! I have to follow all the suggestions and editing you have mentioned. However, the database name is contact, I had to replace contactDB with contact in order to make this work. Thanks a lot for the help!! Anyway, is that localhost connection URL is OK for an embedded DB?

Answer (score 7):

your datasae is already connected disconnect right click -> disconnect now try it ,

it will work sure.

Comment: That worked for me. I had the web application running that was connected to the DB, and I couldn't connect through the IDE as well. But once I've stopped the application I could connect from IDE.

Comment: How to disconnect the database?. I have renamed the database to solve the issue since I did not know how to stop the connection(even after system restart I faced the error so I had to rename the database)

Answer (score 0):

your database is already connected, you have to disconnect. right-click -> disconnect.
and now try again it will work sure.

Answer (score 0):

go to Services >> Databases >>  Java DB >> right-click >>
Stop the Server. and connect your embedded DB.